# Fallacy vs Misconception vs Misnomer

Tags: meaning

Consider the following general statement:

> Somebody with very little credibility is likely to win a debate.

Given that the opposite is most likely true, how can we best describe the above statement? Is it a fallacy, a misnomer, a misconception, or simply a mistake?

If I were to persist in calling this a fallacy, how appropriate would this usage be? I note that Merriam-Webster defines *fallacy* as "a false or mistaken idea", which would surely encompass delusional statements like the one above.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think your example is a fallacy, a misconception *or* a misnomer. It's just false.

To be a fallacy, it would have to be *believed* - *the world is flat* was a fallacy for many years, but is no longer (because no one, to my knowledge, really believes it anymore).

It may be a misconception, which is more or less an incorrect understanding of something, but again, who believes the viewpoint in your example? When you call something a misconception, you're implying that more than one random individual advocates the flawed notion.

A misnomer is something else altogether; it indicates a misapplied or inappropriate name for something. Nothing in your example is named/misnamed.

Comment: I agree - in general, a *fallacy* has to be/have been believed by a significant number of people, so OP's example wouldn't really qualify - no-one, including even OP himself, would give it any credence. On the other hand, I think *Someone with a loud voice...* might be a fallacy, misconception, or simple statement of fact, depending on your point of view.

Comment: Just FYI: [F.E.W. people believe the earth is flat in 2011](http://theflatearthsociety.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

A *misnomer* is the misapplication of a name.   Since your example does not deal with names at all, that doesn't fit.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer) has some good examples of misnomers.  One of my favorites:

> Koala "bear" looks and acts much like a bear, but from a zoologist's point of view it is quite distinct and unrelated.

Between the other two:  misconception and fallacy are very similar in meaning, both referring to incorrect ideas.  From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com):

> Misconception: mistaken notion.
>
> Fallacy: a deceptive, misleading, or false notion, belief, etc.

In my experience, *misconception* is used more often when it's an honest mistake or something that many people believe.  For instance: [List of common misconceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_misconceptions).

*Fallacy*, on the other hand, often has the connotation that the person is either being deliberately deceptive or employing faulty logic.  For [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy):

> Cutting people is a crime. Surgeons cut people, therefore, surgeons are criminals.

@onomatomaniak's example of the world being flat is a tricky one.  Now we know it to be a fallacy, but back in the day when many people believed it, I think one could also legitimately call it a common misconception.

I don't think your example really fits any of these, but at best it's a fallacy.

Comment: I think *the world is flat* can be described as having been a fallacy or a common misconception - the two categories are far from mutually exclusive (in fact, they tend to overlap). That said, I still think the answer to OP's question is that the original example isn't any of these three things. (And just to clarify, a fallacy will never be regarded by its adherents as such - that's just the point.)

Comment: Yep, I agree.  None really fit, but of the three - fallacy is the closest.